# How to compare datetime using createQueryBuilder in TypeOrm?

Tags: typeorm

I am using TypeORM to run this Query But i cannot find how to compare
datetime column in where clause. i found it using find() function, but how to compare using createQueryBuilder? (using MYSQL)

```
this.connection.getRepository(A)
.createQueryBuilder('A')
.leftJoinAndSelect('A.B', 'B', 'A.start_date < NOW() AND A.end_date > NOW() , {where....})
```

If use find() functions.. by docs

```
const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
currentDate: Raw(alias =>`${alias} > NOW()`) });
```

> this is the raw query that i want to run by TypeORM

```
select * from A left join B on A.id = B.id
where A.start_date < NOW() AND A.end_date > NOW()
```

Comment: Your code looks correct `this.connection.getRepository(A).createQueryBuilder('A').leftJoinAndSelect('A.B', 'B', 'A.start_date < NOW() AND A.end_date > NOW()')`

Comment: sorry for late reply it worked! thank you